# Spring lookup method injection with parameters

Tags: spring

Is there a way to use Spring lookup method inject with parameters? For example, I want to be able to instantiate prototype-scoped beans while passing them arbitrary parameters via constructor.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like this vital feature was finally added in Spring 4.1.0.RC2.  I have tested it and it seems to work.

It was added as part of JIRA ticket [SPR-7431 ("Passing lookup-method arguments to created bean constructor")](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-7431):

> <lookup-method/> should allow specifying any number of parameters. These parameters should be passed directly to the constructor of the newly created bean.

For more info on how the feature was finally added, [this blog post](http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2010/08/creating-prototype-spring-beans-on.html) was written by the guy who opened the JIRA ticket.

Answer (score 1):

You can inject them via field/setter injection. (Note that constructor injection is frowned upon by spring, although it's supported)

Comment: Why is there a preference for setter injection over constructor injection? I thought they were equivalent.

Comment: Constructor injection might make instantiating circular dependencies harder.

Comment: @Bozho: so it's actually a good thing... circular dependencies should be used, right?

Answer (score 0):

in short, no. Spring does support something called "method injection" but it's different than you're thinking. Spring also supports constructor injection, but then you're not calling the constructor yourself, Spring is, and wiring it itself.

Instead, you can use reflection to instantiate the class and pass arbitrary parameters yourself:

```
Class<MyObject> clazz = MyObject.class; // this can be looked up or stored in a field, etc.
MyObject myObject = clazz.getConstructor(String.class, int.class)
                         .newInstance("arbitrary parameter", 42);
```